# Can we break the Shannon capacity?

Tags: channelcoding

I have a friend working in wireless communications research. He told me that we can transmit more than one symbol in a given slot using one frequency (of course we can decode them at the receiver).

The technique as he said uses a new modulation scheme. Therefore if one transmitting node transmits to one receiving node over a wireless channel and using one antenna at each node, the technique can transmit two symbols at one slot over one frequency.

I am not asking about this technique and I do not know whether it is correct or not but I want to know if one can do this or not? Is this even possible? Can the Shannon limit be broken? Can we prove the impossibility of such technique mathematically?

Other thing I want to know, if this technique is correct what are the consequences? For example what would such technique imply for the famous open problem of the interference channel?

Any suggestions please? Any reference is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic here, but if not it would probably go well at [cstheory.SE] or [math.SE] or maybe even [dsp.SE].

Comment: I agree this is not so much about physics, but the math underlying signal processing. At the very least, terms like "slot" and "symbol" would need to be better defined here to make sense of the question, whereas they are presumably understood in the signal processing community.